# Reset ant design RangeSelect value after it closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, date-range

I open ant design range select and move to a previous date and then close it without selecting any date or year then I reopen it, but it still shows me the date that I navigated to.

I want to show the current date whenever I open range select unless a date is selected.

Here is my code

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import { LineOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { DatePicker, TimeRangePickerProps } from 'antd';
import { RangePickerProps } from 'antd/es/date-picker';
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { RangeValue } from 'rc-picker/lib/interface';

type PropType = { handleRangeSelect?: (arg1: MaybeNull<string[]>) => void };

export const CustomRageSelect = ({ handleRangeSelect }: PropType) => {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState<RangeValue<Dayjs> | undefined>(null);

  const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
  const today = dayjs();
  const firstDayOfThisWeek = today.startOf('week').add(1, 'days');
  const lastDayOfThisWeek = today.endOf('day'); // Assuming the week ends on Saturday

  const firstDayOfLastWeek = firstDayOfThisWeek.subtract(1, 'week');

  const rangePresets: TimeRangePickerProps['presets'] = [
    { label: 'Today', value: [today, today] },
    { label: 'Yesterday', value: [today.subtract(1, 'day'), today] },
    { label: 'This Week', value: [firstDayOfThisWeek, lastDayOfThisWeek] },
    { label: 'Last Week', value: [firstDayOfLastWeek, firstDayOfLastWeek.add(6, 'days')] },
    { label: 'This Month', value: [today.startOf('month'), today] },
    { label: 'Last Month', value: [today.subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), today.subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')] },
    { label: 'This Year', value: [today.startOf('year'), today] },
    { label: 'Last Year', value: [today.subtract(1, 'year').startOf('year'), today.subtract(1, 'year').endOf('year')] },
    { label: 'All Time', value: null as unknown as [dayjs.Dayjs, dayjs.Dayjs] },
  ];

  const onRangeChange = (dates: null | (Dayjs | null)[], dateStrings: string[]) => {
    if (dates) {
      setDateRange(dates as RangeValue<Dayjs>);
      handleRangeSelect && handleRangeSelect(dateStrings);
    } else {
      setDateRange(null);
      handleRangeSelect && handleRangeSelect(null);
    }
  };

  // const disabledDate: RangePickerProps['disabledDate'] = (current) => {
  //   return current !== null && dayjs(current).isAfter(dayjs(), 'day');
  // };
  const disabledDate: RangePickerProps['disabledDate'] = (current) => {
    const tenYearsAgo = dayjs().subtract(10, 'years');
    return (current !== null && dayjs(current).isAfter(dayjs(), 'day')) || dayjs(current).isBefore(tenYearsAgo, 'day');
  };

  return (
    <RangePicker
      presets={rangePresets}
      onChange={onRangeChange}
      value={dateRange}
      className="btn-style heading5 font-weight-600 font-size-14 "
      separator={<LineOutlined rotate={90} style={{ color: '#E0E0E0', maxWidth: '248px' }} />}
      style={{ minWidth: '240px', gap: '0' }}
      picker="date"
      disabledDate={disabledDate}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the `dateRange` state to default value by using the `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; // Add useEffect

import { LineOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { DatePicker, TimeRangePickerProps } from 'antd';
import { RangePickerProps } from 'antd/es/date-picker';
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { RangeValue } from 'rc-picker/lib/interface';

type PropType = { handleRangeSelect?: (arg1: MaybeNull<string[]>) => void };

export const CustomRageSelect = ({ handleRangeSelect }: PropType) => {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState<RangeValue<Dayjs> | undefined>(null);

  // Reset the date range to the current year and dates whenever the component is rendered
  useEffect(() => {
    const today = dayjs();
    setDateRange([today.startOf('year'), today]);
  }, []);

  const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
  const today = dayjs();
  const firstDayOfThisWeek = today.startOf('week').add(1, 'days');
  const lastDayOfThisWeek = today.endOf('day'); // Assuming the week ends on Saturday

  const firstDayOfLastWeek = firstDayOfThisWeek.subtract(1, 'week');

  const rangePresets: TimeRangePickerProps['presets'] = [
    { label: 'Today', value: [today, today] },
    { label: 'Yesterday', value: [today.subtract(1, 'day'), today] },
    { label: 'This Week', value: [firstDayOfThisWeek, lastDayOfThisWeek] },
    { label: 'Last Week', value: [firstDayOfLastWeek, firstDayOfLastWeek.add(6, 'days')] },
    { label: 'This Month', value: [today.startOf('month'), today] },
    { label: 'Last Month', value: [today.subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), today.subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')] },
    { label: 'This Year', value: [today.startOf('year'), today] },
    { label: 'Last Year', value: [today.subtract(1, 'year').startOf('year'), today.subtract(1, 'year').endOf('year')] },
    { label: 'All Time', value: null as unknown as [dayjs.Dayjs, dayjs.Dayjs] },
  ];

  const onRangeChange = (dates: null | (Dayjs | null)[], dateStrings: string[]) => {
    if (dates) {
      setDateRange(dates as RangeValue<Dayjs>);
      handleRangeSelect && handleRangeSelect(dateStrings);
    } else {
      setDateRange(null);
      handleRangeSelect && handleRangeSelect(null);
    }
  };

  // const disabledDate: RangePickerProps['disabledDate'] = (current) => {
  //   return current !== null && dayjs(current).isAfter(dayjs(), 'day');
  // };
  const disabledDate: RangePickerProps['disabledDate'] = (current) => {
    const tenYearsAgo = dayjs().subtract(10, 'years');
    return (current !== null && dayjs(current).isAfter(dayjs(), 'day')) || dayjs(current).isBefore(tenYearsAgo, 'day');
  };

return (
    <RangePicker
      presets={rangePresets}
      onChange={onRangeChange}
      value={dateRange}
      className="btn-style heading5 font-weight-600 font-size-14 "
      separator={<LineOutlined rotate={90} style={{ color: '#E0E0E0', maxWidth: '248px' }} />}
      style={{ minWidth: '240px', gap: '0' }}
      picker="date"
      disabledDate={disabledDate}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: not worked on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onOpenChange` prop. The documentation says `onOpenChange` is the callback function which can be executed whether the popup calendar is popped up or closed.

So you should listen for when the popup is closed and reset the calendar.

```
// add onOpenChange props to the RangePicker component
const onOpenChange = (isOpen) => {
  if(!isOpen) {
    const today = dayjs();
    setDateRange([today.startOf('year'), today]);
  }
}
```

Comment: still not worked